# reassigning value returned from function generates seg fault

Tags: c, malloc, c99

I have a LDA code in C that I'm trying to debug and I've been banging my head for quite some time now.

```
lda_model *model = NULL;
model = malloc(sizeof(lda_model));
model = quiet_new_lda_model(corpus->num_terms, NTOPICS);
printf ("%f\n", model->alpha); // Segfaults here
```

if we look at the model creation function

```
lda_model* quiet_new_lda_model(int num_terms, int num_topics) {
    int i;
    lda_model* model;

    model = malloc(sizeof(lda_model));
    model->num_topics = num_topics;
    model->num_terms = num_terms;
    model->alpha = 1.0;
    printf ("%f\n", model->alpha); // Prints 1.0
    model->log_prob_w = malloc(sizeof(double*)*num_topics);
    for (i = 0; i < num_topics; i++)
    {
        model->log_prob_w[i] = malloc(sizeof(double)*num_terms);
    memset(model->log_prob_w[i],0,sizeof(double)*num_terms);
    }
    printf ("%f\n", model->alpha); // Prints 1.0
    return(model);
}
```

What could be the problem in the transaction between the `quiet_new_lda_model` function and the original caller?

Thanks!

Comment: Not a fan of checking malloc() for failure, I see...

Comment: Comment out the code that deals with model->log_prog_w and see if it still crashes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, first off, the `malloc` in the caller is unnecessary and is causing a memory leak.  Try replacing those four lines with

```
lda_model *model = quiet_new_lda_model(corpus->num_terms, NTOPICS);
printf ("%f\n", model->alpha); // Segfaults here
```

But that's very unlikely to be the cause of the segfault.  The next thing I would ask is, is a prototype of `quiet_new_lda_model` visible in the caller?  If not, your pointer may be being truncated to `int`.  You can find out by changing all three of the `printf` lines to read

```
printf("%p\n", model);
```

If the third `printf` prints a different value than the first two, a missing prototype is likely to be the problem.

EDIT: Another way to tell if you have a missing prototype is to look for warning messages like this one:

```
test.c:4: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

The phrasing may be different depending on context and which compiler you're using.  If you're using GCC, use the `-Wall` command-line switch to get a stronger hint:

```
test.c:4: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘quiet_new_lda_model’
test.c:4: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

"Implicit declaration" means "you didn't tell me anything about this function so I am going to assume it takes an arbitrary number of parameters and returns `int`."  As you can imagine, this is nearly always wrong.

(As a general rule, if you're using GCC, you should *always* have `-Wall` on the command line.)

Comment: You're right. printf ("%p\n", model) right after the call to quent_new_lda_model is a different number. How do I fix the missing prototype? Is it something I fix in an accompanying header file?

Comment: Just to verify this is the issue, type lda_model* quiet_new_lda_model(int, int); at the top of the code file (first block).

Comment: Did you write the function `quiet_new_lda_model`, or is it from a library you are using?  If it's from a library, then there should already be a header file that declares its prototype; just #include that header.  If it's your code, then you need to make a header file with the prototype, or add the prototype to a header you already have.

Comment: Also, see edit for a way to get the compiler to tell you if this is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the solution but you have a memory leak; you shouldn't allocate model in the first block of code since it's allocated in the function.

I suspect the real root cause is what @Zack suggests - you don't have a prototype so the address which is returned is getting truncated (I am assuming you are on a 64 bit system).

use

```
lda_model* quiet_new_lda_model(int, int);
```

at the top of your first block of code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is a memory leak doing `malloc` in the `quiet_new_lda_model` function without freeing the previously claimed resource.  You shouldn't need to do the malloc in the caller.  Second, where/how is the `lda_model` defined?  Is the header file included in the file where you call the function?

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed the definition of `lda_model` recently? Have you recompiled all source files that use it after the change?

Answer (score 0):

Fix the obvious bug in the code. You've a memory leak which needs fixing. 2ndly to debug your code again, in the higher function do a code like this if(model) printf("%f", model->alfa); Should help you move forward. It cant be predicted but, sometimes, a stack assertion can create a segfault.

Update : Try using '%ld' as opposed to '%f' for a change..Maybe it will help